# How can I load an image from a local directory in PHP?

Tags: php, image, directory, load

My setup (or path) is as follows:

```
 |Home
    |ftpUsername
        |assets
           |images.png
           |script.php
        |mydomain.com
           |index.php
```

*index.php* is located in *mydomain.com*, which includes *script.php* in /home/ftpUsername/assets without a problem. 
 
 *script.php* is included in *index.php* using the *include()* function.
My question is, how can I get PHP to load the images (png format) which are in */home/ftpUsername/assets/* through *script.php*?


In other words:
How can I load */home/ftpUsername/assets/myimage.png* in *script.php*?


Note: /home/ftpUsername/mydomain.com/ is a live directory (is online attached to a domain) and home/ftpUsername/assets/ is not (local directory on the server).

I have tried loading it directly from path using *img src="/home/ftpUsername/assets/myimage.png"* to no avail, with and without a backslash.

Comment: This is a very clear question. All questions should be formatted something like this. The only improvement is that you should show some research effort. What have you tried? What isn't working?

Comment: do you use `include` or `require` function to load _script.php_ in _index.php_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From script.php, you need to read, then output the PNG image (passing the right mimetype, so it will be recognized as an image).

You may use [readfile](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) or even [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) to read filestream, like this: (I'm assuming you'll pass the image name by $_GET 'image'. `/script.php?image=imagename.png` and using a `no_image.png` as a fallback.

```
header("Content-Type:image/png"); //passing the mimetype

$image = '/home/ftpUsername/assets/' . $_GET['image']; 

if(is_file($image) ||  is_file($image = "/home/ftpUsername/assets/no_image.png"))
    readfile($image);
```

This way, you may link your script.png directly in your img src, just like this:

```
<img src="script.php?image=imagename.png" alt="" />
```

Your script.php will act just like an image.